# How to display error in mail sending function using php

Tags: php

problem is cannot display the error in my webpage its not working but error not display . how to display the error in sending fail
my code is given below

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if(isset($_REQUEST))
    {
    $TO = "test@gmail.com";
    $Name           = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $EmailId        = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $messages       = $_REQUEST['message'];
    //FOR MAILING
    $FROM       = "noreply@test.properties";
    $SUBJECT    = "Enquiry From Website";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
       "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n".
       "From: <".$FROM.">\r\n".
       "To: <".$TO.">\r\n".
       "Date: ".date("r")."\r\n".
       "Subject: ".$SUBJECT."\r\n";
    $message = "


    Name                = ".$Name."<br /><br />
    Email Address       = ".$EmailId."<br /><br />
    Comments            = ".$messages."<br /><br />


    ";
    if(@mail($TO, $SUBJECT, $message,$headers))
    {
        header("Location: success.html");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: fail.html");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: remove the `@` from `@mail`. That's suppressing the errors

Comment: Use the real email address and remove @ sign then Upload the php file to your webserver.

Comment: @MatiurRahmanMozumdar: For security purpose, never show real email address that shows in SO.

Comment: Step one is to do as @hungrykoala suggests. Also, the `mail()`-function doesn't always show you errors even if the mail won't send, though. The mail() function only sends the email to the configured mail service (for example sendmail) which just puts it in the mail queue. Then it's that service job to actually send the email. If that fails, PHP is none the wiser.

Comment: I would actually recommend using some tried and tested mail library instead, like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer, and send it through a real SMTP. That will give you a better control and your script will be more portable (since you don't need to have anything else setup on the server).

Comment: could you post your form

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running. To display error if exist, Kindly check 
In your php.ini file check for display_errors. If it is off, then make it on as below:
display_errors = On

Comment: Well, since the first line in the OP's code is `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, I'm quite sure this answer won't make any difference. Specially since the OP also suppresses all errors with `@` before the mail function.

Comment: @AthiraDevi - If you read my comment, you'll realize that you don't need to do that + you won't get any error from the mail() function regardless, since you're literally suppressing the errors using `@` in front of the mail() function. You should really read and respond to the comments.